# How to create a C# WCF application with high availability and performance

Tags: mysql, wcf, load-balancing, high-availability, redundancy

I have developed a C# WCF application, which when called performs inserts and updates in a MySQL 5.6 database, running on a Windows 2008 server, with IIS.  The requests can range from a single update or insert for 1 row, to 1000 updates or 1000 inserts per request.

Initially the 3rd party remote connections was minimal.  But now the load and number of requests has increased.

Therefore, I'm now looking at providing the best possible solutions in terms of a high availability service, with redundant MySQL fail-over; whilst being able to ensure that the service can handle the number of requests; providing rapid response.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to achieve this.